# Python deployment with third-party libraries

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, deployment, exe

I want to deploy an executable (.exe) from my python2.7 project with everything included. I have seen pyinstaller and py2exe but the problem is that my project uses a lot of third-party packages that are not supported by default. What is the best choice for such cases? Is there any other distribution packager that could be used?

Thank you

Comment: PyInstaller and py2exe are actually pretty good at packaging pretty much everything. What do you mean by "third-party libraries that are not supported by default"?

Comment: Sorry I meant packages like http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages . which one is it easier for such cases? And also doesn't give me errors with the MSVCP90.dll?

Comment: If a package is not listed under "SupportedPackages" it does not mean PyInstaller will necessarily fail on it. So your best bet is to try, see how it works, and if it doesn't for some reason, look into the particular error and perhaps discuss it in the corresponding community.

Both py2exe and PyInstaller are good so the choice is a matter of personal preference (I remember liking the latter more). I am not sure what you mean by "errors with the MSVCP90.dll".

Comment: It must be a pretty special, elaborate or non-standard package that it could NOT be automatically handled by pyinstaller. Figuring out and packaging dependencies of a Python program is precisely the domain of pyinstaller. I have had some pyinstaller failures re packaging (big or unusual) dependencies in the past, but nothing that could not be helped by a little tweaking.

Comment: MSVCP90.dll - isn't that some VC++ runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable creation packages should be able to grab 3rd party packages if they're installed. Sometimes you have to specify what to include if the library abuses Python's importing system or it's not a "pure Python" package. For example, I would sometimes have to specifically include lxml to get py2exe to pick it up properly.

The py2exe project for Python 2 hasn't been updated in quite a long time, so I would certainly recommend one of the alternatives: PyInstaller, cx_freeze or bb_freeze.

I have only seen issues with `MSVCP90.dll` when using non pure Python packages, such as wxPython. Normally you can add that in your `setup.py` to include it. If that doesn't work, then you could also add it using an installer utility like NSIS. Or you may just have to state in your README that your app depends on Microsoft's C++ redistributable and include a link to it.